# Accessing single items in an array of images

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, arrays

I was wondering how I would be able to individually access items from the array of images so that I can increase the height/width of the single item rather than the entire class/array.

```
<?php
$imgdir = 'dirimages/';
$images = glob($imgdir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
?>
<script>
    jQuery(function () {
        var phpvar =   <?php echo json_encode($images) ?>;
        $.each(phpvar, function (id, image) {
            jQuery('#slidediv').append('<img class="loadimg" src="' + image + '"/>');
        });

        $('.loadimg').click(function () {
            $('.loadimg').animate({height: '500px', width: '500px'});
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting the entire elements by using its `class` name. Just try to access the current element by using `$(this)`. Additionally, you are `appending` those elements dynamically, so you should use event `delegation` in your context by using `.on()`.

Try,

```
$(document).on('click','.loadimg', function(){
    $(this).animate({height:'500px', width:'500px'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

delegate the event to the closest static parent:

```
$('#slidediv').on('click', '.loadimg', function(){
    $(this).animate({height:'500px',width:'500px'});
});
```

Just because at the page load you did not have the `.loading` element so direct binding of event won't work. so you have to delegate the event to the closest static parent in your case is this `#slidediv` or you can delegate to the `document` itself because that always available in the page.

Also you have bound the event to the class name so that would bind the event to every elem which has that class name, so you need to work the animate function in the context of the current selector using `$(this)`.